# Google Meet extremely slow likely due to Hardware Acceleration

Tags: google-chrome, hardware-acceleration

Every time I enable Hardware Acceleration in order to have visual effects on Google Meet the entire browser (Firefox, Chrome, and Brave) is so slow it's impossible to use.

I've tried installing the latest NVIDIA drivers (nvidia-driver-470), but that didn't help.

What can be done to ensure the browser isn't crawling while hardware acceleration is enabled?

Ubuntu 20.04
GM107M GeForce GTX 960M - Dell XPS 15 9550

Comment: The latest Nvidia drivers aren't always the right choice, it depends on your hardware.

Comment: Is there a table for this (currently on nvidia-driver-470)?

Comment: There isn't a table but there is the search feature at Nvidia's website.